# i cant upgrade pip on centos 7

Tags: python, pip, centos

im trying to pip install requests and it gives me this error
pip2 and pip3 gives the same error
if i use sudo it says that its satisfied and that its installed but when i run the script it still errors

```
python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/ee/74ff76da0ab649eec7581233daeb43d8aa35383d8f75317b2ab3b80c922f/pip-23.1.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-eMIkWJ/pip/setup.py", line 7
        def read(rel_path: str) -> str:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eMIkWJ/pip/
``


ive tried multiple answers from stackoverflow and other sites but i still cant get it to work 
ive also tried looking at multiple different python forms and still didnt get me any where
```